# Owl carousel not working (maybe a conflict?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a fullwidth owl carousel slider to my page, but I cannot get it to work.

I am thinking it could be a conflict with the template I am using.

This is how I added everything:

(After including all owl carousel files of course)

First I included all files:

```
<!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">

<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">

<!--  jQuery 1.7+  -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include js plugin -->
<script src="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Then I added called owl carousel in my header:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();
    });
</script>
```

And finally I added the html code:

```
<!-- slider -->
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="owl-slide"><img src="http://cumbrianrun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/default-placeholder.png"> Slide 1 </div>
    <div class="owl-slide"><img src="http://cumbrianrun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/default-placeholder.png"> Slide 2 </div>
    <div class="owl-slide"><img src="http://cumbrianrun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/default-placeholder.png"> Slide 3 </div>
</div>
<!-- end slider -->
```

But this is the result I get:

[image: Not working]

This is where I want to add the slider: [URL](http://goo.gl/0NIkLT) (shortened url because I don't want this to affect SEO)

Comment: First job of debugging JavaScript; check the console. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://cjpg.eu/assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js`

Comment: Thanks but this does not fix it unfortunately

Comment: It may not fix it, but you will now have a different error or behaviour. Can you check the console and let us know what it says

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is what it says: https://i.gyazo.com/f9e8c481558b326ed136d466fa728883.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error loading you owl.carousel.js file make sure you put the correct path. you have the items styled well but without carousel running because no javascript applied yet!

[image]
**EDIT**

now after putting the correct link you have to add more slides to let the carousel works because all of your slides are appearing now or you can use one slide at once like using the following js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

  navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
  slideSpeed : 300,
  paginationSpeed : 400,
  singleItem:true

   // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
   // items : 1, 
   // itemsDesktop : false,
   // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
   // itemsTablet: false,
   // itemsMobile : false

   });

});
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed that, but still the slider is not working for me.

Comment: @twan You still have js error on your console! check it again

Comment: yes that is google maps related not the slider. I only see one type a error and two warnings.

Comment: @twan it's working now but just if you resize your browser window and make it smaller which mean you have all of your slide shown so no need to carousel. to get it shown you have to put more slides to have 3 shown and the others will get shown by carousel

Comment: Ah I see, any idea how to make it so there is 1 full width tile per slide?